# The components of Levi-Civita tensor(m,n) in 4 dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, gravity, astrophysics

I have an form of Maxwell field in 4 dimension as $F^{mn}=\epsilon^{mn}f(t)$ that $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita tensor and $M,n=0,..3$. Could you please tell me what will be for $F^{02},F^{31}$? I do not actually the value of $\epsilon^{02}$ or $\epsilon^{31}$ .Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The Levi-Civita tensor has 4 indexes in 4 dimensions, and 2 indexes in 2 spacetime dimensions. Either you’re actually working in 2 spacetime dimensions, or your equation is wrong. Either way your question is absurd

Comment: You can see this equation in this paper "https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/33/9/3117/441475/D-dimensional-torus-as-compact-manifold-and-Kaluza?redirectedFrom=fulltext". the equation (3.1) .

Comment: @Alice this article is not freely available to everyone. Secondly, you should make your question self contained to avoid closure due to lack of details / clarity

Comment: I do not know what should I do?Is it possible to upload the paper?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768074/2451

Comment: Hi Alice. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.